# mkdir(): Permission denied when making directories using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, mkdir

I looked everywhere but I still can find the solution to this problem.
I am trying to generate XML files in dedicated directories with some images etc.
But I cant make directories because of the warning: Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in C:\wamp64\www\motor\cpanel.php on line 52

```html
/** create XML file */ 
function generisanje(){
$mysqli = OpenCon2();
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query = "SELECT CONCAT(Ime , Prezime) as Ime, Adresa, broj_Telefona, Drzava, Email, potrosac.id_Potrosaca, Mesto, postanski_Broj, vreme_Narucivanja, proizvodi.Boja, proizvodi.Naziv, proizvodi.Cena, proizvodi.Velicina, proizvodi.Priprema, proizvodi.Primer, proizvodi.Tip, proizvodi.Kolicina FROM potrosac JOIN proizvodi ON potrosac.id_Potrosaca=proizvodi.id_Potrosaca WHERE (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(potrosac.vreme_Narucivanja ,'%d-%m-%y'))=(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(SYSDATE(),'%d-%m-%y')) ";
$narudzbina = array();
//CONCAT(Ime , " ", Prezime)as Ime
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       array_push($narudzbina, $row);
    }
    if(count($narudzbina)){
         createXMLfile($narudzbina);
     }
    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
}
function createXMLfile($narudzbina){
   $id="strasilo";
   foreach ($narudzbina as $komad) {
    $ime        =  strval($komad['Ime']);
    mkdir("naruzbine ". date("d-m-Y")."/".$ime."", true);
   }
   }
```

Above, you can see part of the code that gets a query from MySQL and returns rows, and makes directories based on the Names (Ime) from rows.
I am using WAMP on my Windows laptop.
It's really weird because it works whenever I use a single name from the database. I need names and surnames to be presented as directory names so I need to CONCAT or put two strings together, but whenever I try something like that warning pops up and I end up with no directories.

EDIT: I am sure that $ime make this happen. if I change
$ime        =  strval($komad['Ime']); to
$ime= "some string";
Everything runs as it should but that does not math my use case.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Two things: 1) It might not be creating the directory where you expect, so use an absolute path. 2) Make sure that user that runs the webserver has write permission to the directory you're creating in.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
1) It creates the first directory as usual in the location where I expect it to be created, so I guess the path is fine? The problem is further directories inside of that dir.
2) How can I check that in WAMP?

Comment: What did you change in your edit? It looks like you just undid the indentation improvements that I made.

Comment: Sorry if I did that. 
I added this sentence:
It's really weird because it works whenever I use a single name from the database. I need names and surnames to be presented as directory names so I need to CONCAT or put two strings together, but whenever I try something like that warning pops up and I end up with no directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost my patience and did things in an easy way. So, I worked around this by contacting strings before they enter the database. So I now pull only one variable from the query and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an argument to `mkdir()`. The `$recursive` argument is the third argument, you need to put the permissions before it.

```
mkdir("naruzbine ". date("d-m-Y")."/".$ime, 0777, true);
```

`true` was being treated as `$permissions = 0001`, so it was creating the directory with no write permissions.

Comment: Thank you! I must have lost it in trying to get it working. But unfortunately, it did not solve the problem. I am sure it has something to do with two strings combined in one. So whenever I use any other name for the name of the directory, everything works perfectly. The problem only occurs when I try to use $ime.$prezime or CONCAT them in MySQL etc.

Comment: `/` is a directory separator. So this is creating two directories: `naruzbineDD-MM-YYYY` and a subdirectory `$ime`. Is that what you want?

Comment: You probably need to fix the permissions on the `naruzbindDD-MM-YYYY` directories that were created previously.

Comment: Thank you. My current code looks like this:
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\\naruzbine ". date("d-m-Y")."\\".$ime, 0777, true);
When I echo the path this is the result:
C:\wamp64\www\motor\naruzbine 30-12-2021\Miki Milan - exactly what and where I want it to be. I will try now to first make naruzbine ". date("d-m-Y") folder and then to write inside of it. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to make the first folder first and set it permission but the same thing occurs.

Comment: I lost my patiance and did things on a easy way. So, I worked around this by contacting strings before they enter the database. So I now pull only one variable from the query and everything works as it should.
Since I am new to StackOverflow, should I mark this as solved or?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, and accept that.